# Bootstrap Navbar not expanding on second attempt

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have made a navbar which is responsive and hence on mobile phones, the large bar changes to a button with 'three lines'. When it is clicked, the navbar is supposed to expand(on mobile phones). 
This happens correctly, when I click it for the first time, but after I click it again( to close the navbar) and then click on it again(to open), it **does not** open. Nothing happens. 
Any help why this is happening?
Thanks.
Here is the code I used for navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I've checked your code in bootsnipp.com on chrome emulation mode. Every thing working fine.

Comment: @Akshay Arora make sure that your scripts are loading properly because  your code is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/d9zyoxct/)

Comment: But it works correctly when I click it for the first time. Why doesn't it work for subsequent clicks? What can be the reason? If scripts aren't getting loaded, then it should not work for first time also. Please help.

Comment: I've tried your code in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/dDRXBvDIEj), clicking on the phone icon to emulate the behaviour and all works fine, every time.

Comment: Please mention what version of twitter-bootstrap you're using. Can you create a fiddle?